# What does Pope Francis’s remark, “You can always add more water to the beans,” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, popular-refrains

In connection with my question about Pope Francis’s remark I posted today, there was the following statement in [the same article of New York Times (July 29)](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/30/world/europe/pope-francis-gay-priests.html?hp&_r=0):

> “In contrast, Francis spoke on the beach, engaged with the masses and
>   was greeted like a rock star by followers entranced by his
>   approachable style and homespun folksy adages. “**You can always add
>   more water to the beans**,” he said at one point.”

What does “You can always add more water to the beans,” mean? What benefit do you get by adding  water to the beans? How does it relate to the basic value of Christianity?

Do you have the counterpart English adage to this?

Comment: The beans rehydrate while cooking so you will have to watch them carefully and add more water whenever necessary, and you can add so much water you need whitout run the risk of having beans destroyed. But not even in Italy people use that adage, even if the metaphoric sense is understandable, +1.

Comment: "Add water to beans" is not an idiom. The expression is to be understood in the context in a (nonce) metaphorical sense.

Comment: This isn't really a question about *English* language usage.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree but the OP didn't know that, and in the NY article it wasn't clear the Pope was saying a Latin American proverb. Maybe it will catch on, and you'll know exactly  when, where and why it began! Naa...

Comment: @DJClayworth  There's till part 3 of the OP's request to answer, though. That definitely will be related to the English language. Equivalent adages/proverbs in English or in Italian don't immediately come to mind.

Comment: I don't know of an equivalent expression in English, though the literal translation should be well-enough understood.

Comment: @Marthaª Maybe how there will always be enough [stone soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Soup) to go around. :)

Comment: It might also help if people understood that Brazil’s national dish is [*feijoada brasileira*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feijoada), type of bean stew with assorted piggy bits.

Comment: @tchrist and do people add water to that dish?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Certainly one could, yes. I always think of *feijoada brasileira* when I think of beans in a Brazilian context.

Comment: @Mari-LouA People add water to all bean dishes, that's how you cook beans (all 'normal' dishes, anyway).  If you start with not enough water, you can add more part-way through - but you wouldn't add more beans part way through.  (As long as 'part way' is a significant fraction, more than a tiny bit.)  ... (Actually, never mind - what I just said may be so, but I see from tchrist's answer that it's not really the point.)

Comment: @hunter2  My first interpretation of the phrase as quoted by The NY Times didn't lead me to its correct meaning. It could have been interpreted several ways, I thought adding water to beans, meant something like "It's never too late" or "There's always a solution" or "a small help is better than none at all". It wasn't until I found a Christian journal which correctly reported the sense of Pope Francis's proverb that I realized my initial mistake. I was the second person to post an answer as 48789's answer (at the time) was not very clear to me.

Comment: Only after I had seen the proverb's  context and I *know* that bean soup can be diluted (rarely stew, one would add potatoes and carrots to increase the number of portions not water), did I see that his/her answer was in fact correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes. I was simply responding to your comment to tchrist. I had arrived at a similar (slightly different) interpretation to your 'first read', through the same kind of 'culinary logic'. I was also too hasty - I posted my comment before reading any of the answers, then went back and edited it ("Actually, nevermind...") after reading tchrist's excellent Answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

“To add more water to the beans” is a Latin America saying that means to share what we have with the extra people, to spread it around further. There are songs about this.

The English wording was just a word-for-word verbatim translation.  The actual Latin American phrase would be one of these two, depending on just which one of the two dominant languages there was being spoken at the time:

- Spanish: *poner/echar más agua a los frijoles*
- Brazilian: *botar mais água no feijão*

It’s something of a catch-phrase there.  See [here](http://letras.mus.br/chico-buarque/85966/), [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2064067), [here](http://oglobo.globo.com/pais/noblat/posts/2013/07/26/bota-mais-agua-no-feijao-por-maria-helena-rr-de-sousa-504750.asp), and [here](http://www.m-x.com.mx/2011-01-23/%A1hay-que-echarle-mas-agua-a-los-frijoles/) for a couple of examples in each of Spanish and Portuguese.

On this occasion, Papa Paco made his remark in Portuguese, saying [*sempre se pode colocar mais água no feijão*](http://noticias.terra.com.br/brasil/politica/papa-visita-favela-e-faz-apelo-sempre-se-pode-botar-mais-agua-no-feijao,2ea0ce0594010410VgnCLD2000000dc6eb0aRCRD.html) — “one can always add more water to the *feijão*”. It’s a popular Brazilian saying.  You can [listen to the Pope saying this here](http://mais.uol.com.br/view/1575mnadmj5c/sempre-se-pode-colocar-mais-agua-no-feijao-diz-papa-0402CC18346AC0B14326?types=A&). He has a bit of a Spanish accent, but it’s not bad. :)

A [transcription of his speech](http://www.cnbb.org.br/site/eventos/juventude/12475-papa-francisco-fome-de-uma-felicidade-que-so-deus-pode-saciar) reads:

> Desde o primeiro instante em que toquei as terras brasileiras e também aqui junto de vocês, me sinto acolhido. E é importante saber acolher; é algo mais bonito que qualquer enfeite ou decoração. Isso é assim porque quando somos generosos acolhendo uma pessoa e partilhamos algo com ela – um pouco de comida, um lugar na nossa casa, o nosso tempo  — não ficamos mais pobres, mas enriquecemos. Sei bem que quando alguém que precisa comer bate na sua porta, vocês sempre dão um jeito de compartilhar a comida: como diz o ditado, sempre se pode ‘colocar mais água no feijão’! E vocês fazem isto com amor, mostrando que a verdadeira riqueza não está nas coisas, mas no coração!

In other words, when we are generous and share a bit of food with someone, a place in our home, or our time, we are not left the poorer for it, but richer. He knows that the Brazilians will always find the means to share food with someone at your door who is hungry, because of the saying that one can always throw more water on the bean pot.

In English, we might simply say that “there’ll always be enough to go around”, or to “set another place at the table”.

Comment: Que vive Papa Paco! (I can't find the inverted exclamation point in Character Map.  Grr...)

Comment: +1, but if I were you I would delete the "*He has a bit of a Spanish accent, but it’s not bad. :)*" part!

Comment: @Carlo_R. It was a little joke, Carlito, a slight jest, una broma, un chiste. I could just as well have said that he had a bit of an American sotaque, which would have been true but misunderstood.

Comment: @MT_Head So now you get to insert *“[pace Papa Paco]”* into your speech wherever you can. It’s nearly impossible to say with a classical/hard C in the first word especially three times fast. :)

Comment: This saying somehow reminds me of the [old fable about stone soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Soup), but I can’t quite put my finger on why.

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. A variant used in some parts is "echarle más agua al caldo" or adding more water to the soup. If you had cooked lunch for four, and a sudden visitor arrives, you can just 1 more cup of water (plus salt and seasoning) and all can share the meal. Be generous with what you have.

Answer (score 5):

I was interested in that as well, and looking online it appears that it is a Latin American saying intended to encourage generosity. A suggestion to spread what you have even when it's not a lot.

Comment: Sounds very plausible and convincing. Would be better if you can include some citation(s).

Answer (score 5):

To me this expression means simply that adding extra water to a pot of beans makes the soup thinner but yields more servings. It also echoes (as I'm sure the Pope was aware) the "loaves and fishes" episode in the New Testament, where Jesus and his followers despite having little for themselves (five small barley loaves and two fishes, according to John 6:9), miraculously feed thousands of people with them. In that case, of course, the food wasn't diluted or reduced to tiny serving portions prior to being distributed. But a poor person cooking beans can't count on miraculous multiplication of the ingredients.

In English, we have a somewhat related expression, notably favored by Dorothy Day of the Catholic Worker:

> There's always room for one more. Everyone take a little less.

indicating that a meal for an expected number can always be stretched to accommodate an unexpected guest. The website proz.com notes that a Spanish proverb says much the same thing:

> Donde comen dos comen tres.

That is, "Where two eat, three eat."

The most relevant maxims related to generosity among the poor that I could find in *The Facts on File Book of Proverbs* (1983) are

> Poor and liberal, rich and covetous.

and

> The higher the hill, the lower the grass.

both of which imply that poor people are more open-handed than wealthy people are. I have never heard either of these expressions used in the United States.

Comment: My grandma (a Southerner who moved to California) had an expression that I've been trying to remember, very close to "you can always add more water..." (except it wasn't about beans.) The idea was that the door is always open to guests - even if there are more of them than you expected - and everybody gets to eat. It's driving me nuts that I can't remember it.

Comment: +1 for linking the proverb with the fishes and loaves "miracle" and for the equivalent English saying.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:2** Below was my *first* interpretation of the adage, which nevertheless led me to arrive at the correct conclusion. See EDIT at the end. Knowing how to cook has its advantages! :)

If you have ever tried cooking dried borlotti beans, you will know instantly what this *piece of advice* or more appropriately, *adage*, is referring to. These dried pulses popular in Italy and I imagine in Latin America too, need to be soaked first in cold water. Sometimes, depending how dry they are, 8 or more hours is necessary. (One of the factors why nowadays many prefer to buy the frozen or tinned variety) In boiling these beans, judging the quantity of water needed can be tricky. Too much and most of their goodness is dispersed in the water which is then thrown away. Such a pity and a waste. Too little, and you risk burning the beans. This happened to me once; a thick impenetrable layer of black crust at the bottom of the pan.

So, what many cooks do is to cover the beans with just enough water and while the beans boil keep an eye on the water level. As the beans absorb the water, more is added to "top up". Hence the Pope Francis's phrase: "**You can always add more water to the beans**" 
Obviously he was speaking metaphorically, I don't think he was actually giving cooking instructions. :)

[image]

EDIT: This adage or proverb is new to me. I've never heard it in either the UK or in Italy. In the context of the Papal visit in Brazil; [source](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/deaconsbench/2013/07/john-allen-on-what-we-learned-about-the-pope-in-brazil/)

> "During a visit to a Rio slum, for instance, he said the poor are
>   often the most generous folk, quoting a Latin American proverb: “You
>   can always add more water to the beans.”

It suggests that even if new guests, unexpected visitors or friends arrive at your doorstep you can always share your food with them. In the example of the beans, it probably means that if you are making a zuppa di fagioli (bean soup), you can increase the portions simply by adding water.

Comment: OK: It's a metaphor. For what?

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Italians don't have this metaphor but I imagine it means, it's "never too late to save the day", type of thing.

Comment: I will add an edit to my answer.

Comment: @Andrew, I think it means that eucharistic adoration can help us continue to savor the taste of “how good is the Lord”, but, frankly, I have to say that I am not an expert of these things.

Comment: Thanks. +1. I really don't think popes should speak in riddles!

Comment: @Andrew, but I don't see my comment upvoted!

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The impression I got was that his intention was to relate to the crowd he was addressing - which seems to have worked, and gone over well. The fact that he used a locally-understood expression, which was picked up by international media and translated into various languages and then NOT understood by people who weren't anywhere near him at the time... not really his fault, I think. Popes aren't infallible except when writing/speaking _ex cathedra_; apparently they're not universally translatable either.

Comment: @MT_Hea, as I told to Andrew, I think it means that "adding water to the beans" (read, metaphorically, eucharistic adoration) can help us continue to savor the taste of “how good is the Lord”; so even if you cannot universally translate it, its sense, as far as I know, is surely universal.

Comment: No, it doesn't @Carlo_R. The saying has *nothing* to do with: "To *savour the taste* of how good is the Lord" See Sven Yargs's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, when you add water to the beans you're (theoretically) allowing more people to join to your meal. You can share more, divide your food with more persons just by adding water. It's a trick made by poor people who are unable to buy more beans for everyone, so it means a "fudge", in a good sense.